# verify an Isabelle proof from the command line

Tags: command-line, isabelle

How can I verify that a *.thy file is a valid Isabelle proof from the command line? Doing it in the GUI amounts to seeing that there are no issues/errors/warnings etc, I guess. But is there a way to do it from the command line?

Answer (score 6):

You just have to write a small ROOT-file and then invoke `isabelle build`.
E.g., if you want to check that theories `Foo.thy` and `Bar.thy` compile, then you create a file with name `ROOT` with the following content:

```
session Test = HOL + 
theories
  Foo
  Bar
```

Then the compilation can be done via

```
isabelle build -d. Test
```

See the Isabelle system manual (Chapter 2) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid having to create a `ROOT` file, you might be able to do something like:

```
isabelle process -T Foo
```

But `isabelle build` is certainly the “more official” way.

Something similar (with a hackish dance to set the secure mode for some theories) is what the [Praktomat does to submitted Isabelle theories](https://github.com/KITPraktomatTeam/Praktomat/blob/master/src/checker/checker/IsabelleChecker.py).

Comment: What does Praktomat do now that secure mode doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: I guess the Isabelle support there is a bit stale :-)